# How to run and install a download python package from the GitHub website?

Tags: python, github

I want to fully download this package, which I downloaded from the GitHub website, but I do not know how to run this package. There is no file named [setup.py] in the package that came with the command [python setup.py install] I install it and when I download a package from the GitHub website, how should we run that package? What order does it mean? How to run on a Windows system when we download a Python package that we download from the GitHub website? How to run the whole download package? Please explain in full
The address of the packet download in the GitHub:
https://github.com/ironman5366/W.I.L.L
Help me please
Thank you

Comment: It doesn't look like it is supposed to be a python package for you to install on your computer

Comment: Why not install on my computer?

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to download the program and host it on your own computer, so that you can interact with the API? Because they do host it themselves (as stated in the repo), meaning you can interact with the API without downloading and running it yourself. Or do you want to download it in order to make changes to the program?

Comment: I want to download this app and run it completely. Then apply the changes in the program. I just have this problem. I do not know how to run it.i want run on my local cimputer

Comment: Do not run these Errors now? I do not know how to solve these problems?

Comment: What were the errors again? Your previous post was deleted. Please post them as text, and not as a screenshot. You were missing two modules or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As FlyingTeller and mgracer pointed out in the comments, the github repo is not a python package, and thus can not be installed as a package. It's a [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/%20flask) server, which you can download and run on your local machine.

Without having looked too closely at it, the will.py script seems to be the one running the server. Try downloading and running it like a normal python script:

```
python will.py
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
But not installed

Comment: Do you need to install all the requirements?

Comment: You can install all the requirements with `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: thank you Bart, Is going to be done.

Comment: To install the requirements, this brings up.  Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\KING-M~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-qmtpkz93\shapely\